# Solving unusual "out of range" error behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, text, find-occurrences

I'm creating C# winforms app which has to find all occurences of a string within a file, crop the text in between, then do some processing.

The text file has following format:

> ---- Key_String ----

> text to crop 1

> ---- Key_String ----

> text to crop 2

> ---- Key_String ----

> text to crop 3

Basically I'm croping "text1", "text2", "text3" from that file.

And here is the code to do the mentioned action:

```
string contents = "";
MatchCollection matches;
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
{
    contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    matches = Regex.Matches(contents, "Key_String");
}
int totalmatchcount = matches.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < totalmatchcount; i++ )
{
    int indd1 = matches[i].Index;
    int indd2 = 0;
    string sub_content = "";
    if (i != totalmatchcount - 1)
    {
        indd2 = matches[i+1].Index;
        try
        {
            sub_content = contents.Substring(indd1, indd2); // error here
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Index 1: "  + indd1 + "\n" +
                "Index 2: "  + indd2 + "\n" +
                "Max index (length - 1): "  + (contents.Length - 1)
                );
        }
    }
    else { sub_content = contents.Substring(indd1); }
    // do some stuff with "sub_content"
}
```

It works great for some of my files, however in some cases - I'm getting following error:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
> Parameter name: length

It is very strange, because the substring that I'm cropping is located INSIDE the main string, not outside as you have guessed. I can prove it with "try-catch" output:

> Index 1: 3211

> Index 2: 4557

> Max index (length - 1): 5869

As you can see - I'm not cropping something that is located outside the index range, so what's the problem?

P.S. I've googled solutions but the basic idea in every case is - "wrong index". In my case - index is "inside" the range. Well, at least I think so.

### Edit

Something similar to this should solve the problem:

```
 public string SubstringFix(string original, int start, int end)
    {
        int endindex = 0;
        if (end < original.Length)
        {
            endindex = end;
        }
        else
        {
            endindex = original.Length - 1;
        }

        return original.Substring(start, (end - start));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Substring` does not take two indices. It takes one index and a length. Probably, you want

```
indd2 - indd1
```

as the second parameter (and check that expression for off-by-one errors).

Comment: Ooops my bad ;( I've never expected to fail this much. Sorry for obviously stupid question.. and +1 to your rep.

Comment: @Alex Don't feel too bad. `Substring` implementations across languages tend to vary. I still occasionally have to stop myself when I make a `Substring` call to remember if it's length or EndIndex that I want.

Comment: Just to add, _some_ languages seem to want to play psychological warfare with you and have both implementations but only slight ambiguous variations in the name.  JavaScript for example: http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/01/substr-vs-substring-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

With what you have this is what you are getting

```
3211+4557 = 7768
```

and that is greater than the length of the string.

This is how substring works

```
substring(startindex, length)
```

Length of string should not be less than startIndex + length